# Angular - Best Way to structure business logic

Tags: angular

I'm just trying to work out the best way to structure my components / logic

My scenario is I have an angular component with a DTO containing a set of properties, and there is some logic based on those properties that I want to use on multiple components

```
// ngonit
this.dto$ = this.service.getDto(1); // call to API returning observable<DTO>
```

Then in my template file, something like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dto$ | async as d">
  ....
  <span *ngIf="d.ComplexConditionIWantToShare()">.....</span>
  .... 
</ng-container>
```

I understand this is a bad practice since you shouldn't use methods in the template file as it causes performance issues. (and the complex method won't exist by default using TS since its initialized/deserialized by the JSON serializer.)

But I don't want to expose all the conditional logic into the template if possible as it avoids dry principles / etc

I can think of a few options but not really sure which is the recommended / best practice... any guidance?

thank you for taking the time.

Comment: You could: 1) add this conditional property to the DTO on the server before sending it to the client app; or 2) add this property in the client app after you have received the DTO. Either may be acceptable, it depends on whether you want to hide that logic from the user or if it's particularly performance intensive to calculate the conditional property. My advice would be to make it work first and then optimise it later.

Answer (score 0):

Personally it is my backend that applies the business logic of my application, the frontend only displays / processes forms.
I've already seen projects working with something similar but I'm not a fan and I have a hard time seeing why to do that.

In the end it's a service you use?

Comment: Yeah - I agree with you. This is for UI related conditional logic. I guess you are recommending 'flattening' that logic into a pre-calculated boolean property on the backend and re-use that throughout the front-end? This was one of the options i was considering. thanks!